# getgauge How to get All Steps using GelAllStepList?

Tags: gauge, getgauge

I want to get all Step informations for scenarios using on BeforeScenario Method. So I tried to get with *getAllStepsList()* method. But everytime ***return "0"***. Could you please help me, how can I do it?

```
Api.GetAllStepsResponse.getDefaultInstance().getAllStepsList()
```

Regards,

Comment: can you please explain more on what you are trying to achieve ? and  where you are trying do this ?

Comment: Hi @par, I want to get all step list when scenario run has started. Because I want to see that all scenario steps (Passed, Failed or Not Started) And I'm trying to **BeforeScenario**, but I'm not sure that is correct.

Comment: step execution status will be available in execution context on `afterStep` to find if the scenario is failed `afterScenario` can be used. Please refer https://docs.gauge.org/latest/writing-specifications.html#current-execution-context-in-the-hook

Comment: I know it. But I want to get all steps. For ex: My scenario have 10 steps. And  3rd steps  threw fail, so test scenario return failed. Right now, I want to get all of the steps. Because, I need the remaining steps for the correct reporting. Now, how can I get all steps (10 step) information everytime?

Answer (score 0):

The `API` package is meant to be consumed by IDEs which open `gauge` as a daemon, and communicate with it. What you see is the default value of an empty instance.

The information about steps in a scenario is available with gauge when it parses the spec file. This information is not relayed to the runner or the user code currently. Please feel free to log an issue if you'd like to see such meta information here: https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/new.